# CodeIgniter route is not working, throwing 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to load a route, but it's not working. Here is my code:

**ROUTE:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['register'] = 'Register_controller';  //  Not  working
$route['register/thankyou'] = 'Register_controller';  //  Not  working
```

**Register Controller:**

```
class Register_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    public function thankyou()
    {
        $this->load->view('thankyou');
    }
}
```

**VIEW :**

> I HAVE register.php and thankyou.php page on view section

Why is it not working?

It's displaying a CodeIgniter 404 page.

Comment: What is "Codignator"? Do you mean [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add method name in controller as following.

```
$route['register'] = 'Register_controller/index'; 
$route['register/thankyou'] = 'Register_controller/thankyou';
```

or

```
$route['register'] = 'register_controller/index'; 
$route['register/thankyou'] = 'register_controller/thankyou';
```